# Python: remove dictionary from list, given list of keys to remove

Tags: python

I have an extension question to [remove dictionary from list](http://Python:%20remove%20dictionary%20from%20list), except that I have a list of dictionary keys I would like to remove from the list.

So, I have something like:

```
a=[{'id': 1, 'name': 'paul'},{'id': 2, 'name': 'john'},{'id': 3, 'name': 'john2'},{'id': 4, 'name': 'johnasc'}]
```

now, I have a del_list, like so:

```
del_id_list=[2,4]
```

what is the efficient way (assuming list `a` is LARGE) to delete dictionaries with `id` from `del_list` from `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get acquainted with [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
result = filter(lambda x: x['id'] not in del_id_list,a)
```

EDIT:

Regarding the `del_id_list` itself, if it's long you may want to consider the complexity of the `in` statement. Maybe a `set` and even a `dict` (with arbitrary value) would be better. Check [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

EDIT 2:
As @Jean correctly points out, this is a iteration sequence in Py3. Just add list:

```
result = list(filter(lambda x: x['id'] not in del_id_list,a))
```

Comment: in python 3, filter won't execute, you have to iterate through it to get the result (`list(filter ....`)

Answer (score 2):

one way, recreating the list using a list comprehension (and declaring `del_id_list` as a `set` for faster lookup):

```
a=[{'id': 1, 'name': 'paul'},{'id': 2, 'name': 'john'},{'id': 3, 'name': 'john2'},{'id': 4, 'name': 'johnasc'}]
del_id_list={2,4}

new_a = [d for d in a if d['id'] not in del_id_list]
```

result:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'paul'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'john2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sourceList = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'paul'},{'id': 2, 'name': 'john'},{'id': 3, 'name': 'john2'},{'id': 4, 'name': 'johnasc'}]

del_id_list = [2,4]

for itemDict in sourceList:
  if itemDict['id'] in del_id_list:
    sourceList.remove(itemDict)

print(sourceList) 

Result -> [{'name': 'paul', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'john2', 'id': 3}]
```